# Power Automate multi Level approval Workflow adding Attachment at each level

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process

I'm looking for solution approach for below requirement.

I have 6 levels of approval. Once user initiates request it will send to level 1 then once level 1 approve it. It goes to level 2 but mein while user make modifications in the request and add one more attachment with updating metadata. Same will happen till level 6 also approver can send request back to previous level if need any additional details.

Can you please guide me how can we achieve this using power automate and SharePoint list.

Comment: well if they are not approving the specific version of the request, then think about it as a stages..Create a choice column "Request Stage" with 7 stages (6 + "Completed"). Then in Power Automate Flow "Start and wait for an approval" select "custom Responses" and insert there Options: Level 1, Level 2....Level 6 < so each level can send it to whatever stage they want to...In the Power Automate you can use "Switch" action to do specific job for each stage (google "State Machine" it might give you more details). 6th Level should have options "Finish Request" to close the circle.